# jitsi-android unable to compile and build

Tags: java, android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to compile and run the project
**https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-android** on Eclipse by Importing.

I have imported the project successfully,Added External Jar files and Fix some of compilation errors.

When I try to run app, It is giving

**Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1** Error on the console.So that I Clean the project, checked the all the jar files from Order and Export tab and build it again.

but it doesn't work for me.

Finally, I uncheck the all the libraries from Order and Export tab,build and run it again.

This time it worked for me, but throws **noclassdeffounderror** Error and App crashed.

I want to compile and run this app.

Please help,
Thanks !!!

Comment: Hey Sharath , I am also facing same problem , have you found any solution of this ..i am stuck at this point from last night but haven't found any solution to get rid of this problem....your help will be greatly appreciated .. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I tried alot but didn't find any solution to fix this.

Comment: okay , thanks for your reply

Comment: Welcome.I wish at least you could success.Good luck my friend

Comment: @Sharath, I am also stuck with same issue.Have you found any solution? please reply. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

After struggle, Finally I am able to build compile the project successfully. In the project there are contain **build.xml** file. So, It need be run using the ant (First need to install the ant and then set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable).

Don't need to change anything in code related to importing package name. It will be fixed the error automatically after build. In some classes may get the IOException error(Need to change to Exception type).

Please follow the below step:-

1. After updating library bundles, when building for the first time or after clean:

**ant setup-libs**

2. To make the project:

**ant make**

3. To rebuild (clean and make):

**ant rebuild**

4. To run the project (will install the apk and will run it on default test device):

**ant run**

5. To make and run the project after modification:

**ant make run**

I hope this will help to others. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi jagdish,Congratulation. Is it possible to run the "jitsi-android" library in android ADT or Eclipse? or It only runs in the "ant" tool?

If it runs on the Eclipse as well, Please share the steps.

Thanks for sharing and Congrats again for chasing the Issue.

Comment: @Sharath, Thanks..:) In eclipse we can do the customization/modification as per our requirement. But need to be run from ant. It will detect the device and run the build.